# How to add new IRQ mapping in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm using Armbian Linux OS and OrangePI 3 LTS ARM Board. I want to add new IRQ (interrupt) mapping between hardware and system level. I see that mapping is probably done in /proc/irq directory and probably is added during boot phase of Linux. Question here: how to create new mapping to IRQ. From HW IRQ source i.e. 35 to system level (another number) during boot?

I tried to find answer in google.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Mapping is done in DTS file. Device Tree Overlay. Needed to change status from "disabled" to "okay" in dts file. After this IRQ is mapped correctly to system level and IRQ is correctly registered by driver after load Linux kernel driver.